# PDO - Selecting Columns coming from POST/Parameter

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is it possible to have this function:

```
function getProjectData($uid, $what) {
    $sql = "SELECT ? FROM projects WHERE fid = ?";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($uid,$what);
    return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
}
```

"uid" is the user id and "what" would be the column I want e.g. "title" so the query would be:

```
SELECT title FROM projects WHERE fid = 1
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table and Column names cannot be replaced in PDO:

Take a look here:
[Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table or column name as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter)

Answer (score 1):

```
function getProjectData($uid) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE fid = ?";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($uid);
    return $stmt->fetch();
}
```

call it this way

```
$proj_data = getProjectData($uid);
```

and then get desired properties as

```
$title = $proj_data[$what];
```